# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, marionette

I have a composite view:

```
var resultView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template : ResultPanel,
        itemView : ResultItemView,
        initialize : function() {
            ...
        },
        itemViewOptions : {
            app : this.options.app
        },
```

I just want to assign this view's app property to itemView's app property. So i can use this view's app from other view. But I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined.  What am i doing wrong? Is there another way in order to do this?

Comment: You want to pass the app variable through the constructor? this refers to the {} object when declaring this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possiblity #1:
this.option is not yet set when your code executes.

possibility #2:
maybe 'this' is not what you expect it to be. 
assign  var that = this; 
before and use 'that' instead of 'this'.

or assign var _options = this.options; before extend() and use _options in the extend.

Answer (score 0):

`options` will be generated from the object that you supply to the constructor of your view. It includes everything except for things like `model` and `collection`

```
var rv = new resultView({model: something, app: something})
```

Which can then be accessed like so

```
var resultView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        itemView : ResultItemView,
        initialize : function(options) {
             this.app = options.something;    
        },
        itemViewOptions : {
            app : this.options.app
        },
```

If you want to refer to these options in another method, you will need to attach the required variables to the view (`this`) itself.

You can't access things like the `model` from the options parameter, however they will automatically be attached to your view